# PyQt5 shortcut in menubar is not working

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a simple UI that has the functionality to close when I use the shortcut `Ctrl+Q` or when I use the Exit into the File menu, to make it clearer I've created a fairly simple UI that goes with the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp


class MGen(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        exit_action = QAction('Exit', self)
        exit_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exit_action.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        menu_bar = self.menuBar()

        file_menu = menu_bar.addMenu('&File')
        file_menu.addAction(exit_action)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('MGen')

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mgen = MGen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Could anyone point what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your code is working as expected on Archlinux/PyQt5 5.8

Comment: could it be because of some package missing?